Find all differentiable functions $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} ≡\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.
I saw this problem:  Find all differentiable functions $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to  \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} ≡\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.
I tried to make some guess like $f(x,y)- f(y,x)= C$ but I wasn't able to prove that this is the only solution or if there is other solutions.

Hint: Consider the partial derivatives of $g(x,y)=f(x,y)-f(y,x).$

A key phrase to look up is "transport equation".
